# My application.properties isn't finding enviroment variables from docker-compose

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, spring-cloud

I am trying to connect my app with a mysql database I've tried several different ways and I keep getting the same error "URL must start with 'jdbc'" but I already have that enviroment variable in my docker-compose:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframe
work/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: URL must start with 'jdbc'
```

## docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  products-service:
    container_name: products-service
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=jdbc:mysql://products_db:3306/products_service?createDatabaseIfNotExist=TRUE&serverTimezone=UTC
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=root
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=root
    depends_on:
      - products_db
    networks:
      - "products-network"
  products_db:
    container_name: products_db
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=products_service
networks:
  products-network:
```

## application.properties:

```
application.name=products-service

server.port=8081

spring.datasource.url=${DATABASE_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${DATABASE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.instance.lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds=0
```

And I let an image of my project, as you can see the docker-compose is there

[project image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFNCL.png)

Comment: Are you actually using the docker compose to start the service or are you just running the main method from your IDE? As the latter will not work. Also why the complexity with the parameter re-write? Just pass `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` as an environment parameter and remove the `spring.datasource.url` (and others) from the `application.properties`. Spring Boot will automatically use the one from the environment, no need to add additional complexity by replacing it.

Comment: I am trying to "mvn install" so I get the JAR file and finally run the docker-compose (actually de Dockerfile needs the JAR).
On the other hand, I didn't really understand what you mean by complexity, I am just watching some tutorials where they connect a service to a db, also I've checked some repos and they do it like this

Comment: You don't need `spring.datasource.url=${DATABASE_URL}` if you set `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` as the environment property. The mapping you do is additional complexity. Docker compose doesn't build the image, so if you only have the jar and no new image it won't do a thing.

Comment: The error was during  testing so by adding this to the pom <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip> I was able package my project and run my docker-compose which has the enviroment variables